# How to create a PL SQL procedure to display all records from relation Employee

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Write a PL/SQL Procedure to display all the records in employee table as “The Employee  has a ID  working in  Department”.

I have created a procedure but it is created with compilation errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee_information
AS
BEGIN
FOR aRow IN (SELECT NAME,ID,DEPARTMENT FROM Employee)
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line ("Employee name" || aRow.NAME "having ID " || aRow.ID "working in" || aRow.DEPARTMENT)
END LOOP;
END get_employee_information ;
/
```

Can you please write a simple to understand procedure , as I am new to PL SQL.
After correcting its still getting created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_Employees_Information
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4  FOR aRow IN (SELECT NAME,ID,DEPARTMENT FROM EMPLOYEE)
  5  LOOP
  6  dbms_ouput.put_line (' The Employee ' || aRow.NAME );
  7  dbms_ouput.put_line (' having ID ' || aRow.ID );
  8  dbms_ouput.put_line (' working in department ' || aRow.DEPARTMENT );
  9  END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /
```

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
Can anyone please help me out !

Comment: In `sql*plus`, type `show errors` to see the compilation errors.  If that doesn't help you fix the code, please edit your question to include the errors.

Answer (score 1):

line 6 does not correctly use concatenation (`||`). You can't just put a variable next to a constant, as in the fragment `aRow.NAME "having ID "`. Also, in SQL, unfortunately string literals belong in single quotes, not double quotes.

you've misspelled `dbms_output`. if you really wanted everything in a single line you should have done

```
dbms_output.put_line( 'text ' || field || ' text ' || field || ... )
```